# Boost (1.76.0) Error during Caffe Build OSX

Tags: boost, cmake, homebrew, caffe, boost-python

I am dealing with a little snag that came up while trying to build Caffe from source. First, I will describe the steps I took and then the error itself.

```
git clone https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/caffe
mkdir build; cd build
brew install boost
brew install boost-python3
```

The following change to CMakeCache.txt to help CMake find veclib (idk if this is relevant):

```
vecLib_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=vecLib_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND -> vecLib_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/
```

Here is the relevant part of caffe/build/Dependencies.cmake:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost 1.54 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread filesystem)
list(APPEND Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
list(APPEND Caffe_LINKER_LIBS PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Afterwards from caffe/build

```
cmake ..
```

Which produces the following log:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Misc.cmake:32 (set):
  implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found Boost 1.76.0 at /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS system;thread;filesystem
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_headers 1.76.0 at /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.76.0
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_system 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_system 1.76.0 at /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is clang10 (Clang 10.0.1.10010046)
-- Scanning /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_system-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_system-mt.a
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_system.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.76.0/libboost_system-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_system.a
-- Adding boost_system dependencies: headers
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_thread 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_thread 1.76.0 at /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is clang10 (Clang 10.0.1.10010046)
-- Scanning /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_thread-mt.a
-- Adding boost_thread dependencies: headers
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_filesystem 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_filesystem 1.76.0 at /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is clang10 (Clang 10.0.1.10010046)
-- Scanning /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_filesystem-mt.a
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem.a
-- Adding boost_filesystem dependencies: headers
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.54") found components: system thread filesystem 
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.dylib)
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libglog.dylib)
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/local/bin/protoc
-- Found lmdb    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/liblmdb.dylib)
-- Found LevelDB (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libleveldb.dylib)
-- Found Snappy  (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libsnappy.dylib)
CMake Warning at cmake/Dependencies.cmake:92 (message):
  -- CUDA is not detected by cmake.  Building without it...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- OpenCV found (/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib/cmake/opencv4)
-- Found vecLib as part of Accelerate.framework
-- NumPy ver. 1.8.0rc1 found (include: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include)
-- Found Boost 1.76.0 at /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET COMPONENTS python
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake)
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_python 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_python 1.76.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/boost_python-config.cmake:29 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/../BoostDetectToolset-1.76.0.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package)
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:182 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Scanning /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/libboost_python-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/libboost_python-variant-mt-shared-py3.9.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_python39-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/libboost_python-variant-mt-static-py3.9.cmake
--   [x] libboost_python39-mt.a
--   Setting Boost_PYTHON_VERSION to 3.9
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/libboost_python-variant-shared-py3.9.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_python39.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/libboost_python-variant-static-py3.9.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_python39.a
-- Adding boost_python dependencies: headers
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.46") found components: python 
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0
--   Git               :   1.0-149-g1807aada-dirty
--   System            :   Darwin
--   C++ compiler      :   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   ON
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   ON
--   CPU_ONLY          :   OFF
--   USE_OPENCV        :   ON
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   ON
--   USE_LMDB          :   ON
--   USE_NCCL          :   OFF
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
--   USE_HDF5          :   ON
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (vecLib)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.76)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. ..)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.29)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.23)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. 1.1.9)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 4.5.2)
--   CUDA              :   No
-- 
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.16)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (ver 2.7.10)
--   NumPy             :   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.0rc1)
-- 
-- Documentaion:
--   Doxygen           :   No
--   config_file       :   
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /Users/[REDACTED]/workspace/internships/reu_gmu/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/build/install
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/[REDACTED]/workspace/internships/reu_gmu/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

The error responsible for the failure is:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/boost_python-config.cmake:29 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/../BoostDetectToolset-1.76.0.cmake
```

What is BoostDetectToolset-1.76.0.cmake? I tried placing this file: https://github.com/boostorg/boost_install/blob/develop/BoostDetectToolset.cmake (after renaming) at the above file path but the error persists. I am embarrassed to admit I also tried commenting out line 29 in boost_python-config.cmake. cmake ran fine, make failed. Could the absence of the file be symptomatic of boost-python3 incompatability with this caffe build? I have Conda installed and I may have forgotten to deactivate the base environment in the beginning, maybe this led to the issue somehow (different python versions at different points during the build process)
I tried:

```
brew install boost-python
```

but it failed. Maybe this will be patched in the future. Is it more advisable at this point to switch to an alternative like pybind11?

UPDATE:
Error after steps in fourth comment in thread below were taken:

```
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: python-py395 (found /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.46"))
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: python-py39 (found /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.46"))
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: python-py3 (found /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.46"))
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/boost_python-config.cmake:29 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.76.0/../BoostDetectToolset-1.76.0.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package)
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:175 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)
```

Comment: Since you installed `boost-python3`, I assume you want to build with Python 3.x? Because right now it's also picking up Python 2.7, and accordingly tries to find the Python 2 variant of `boost-python`. | https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/caffe/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L35

Comment: Yea boost-python is unavailable on brew at the moment. Is it alright if I rebuild with conda python (3.8.3)? Then I could use boost-python3. I read somewhere a while ago that Anaconda and Homebrew is a volatile mixture, is that true?

Comment: No idea, haven't used either of those. | I see that you have `libboost_python39-mt.a`, meaning brew installed boost-python built for Python 3.9. And since it's a package manager, I'd expect (based on my experience with similar tools) that it would also make sure the dependencies (i.e. the right version of Python) would be installed too. So I'd check that, and then try to build Caffe against 3.9 as well. | Either change the line I pointed out above, or just call CMake with `-D python_version=3`.

Comment: Ok, I added ```export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"``` to .bash_profile to set the system-wide python version to 3.9 just in case this is necessary (now ```python --version``` returns 3.9.5). Then deleted CMakeCache.txt to wipe any memory of python 2 builds and ran ```cmake -D python_version=3 ..``` from build. The build fails claiming Boost incompatibility with python 3.9 (see error posted below UPDATE). Maybe I should manually point BoostConfig.cmake to python 3.9 filepath or something? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: The errors disappeared after I deleted all lines related to Anaconda setup in ~/.bash_profile, took the warnings emitted by ```brew doctor``` seriously, ran ```brew uninstall caffe```, and removed the first two lines in Dependencies.cmake       
(```set(BOOST_ROOT "usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0") set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)```). I think that's it, there may be some other things I'm forgetting though so will leave this as a comment rather than an answer. Your advice was very helpful @DanMasek, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you figure this out.